# Why the List of items from the request is empty while uploading image using servlet

Tags: java, forms, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am tryng to upload an image using a servlet and the main part of the servlet in the post method is as follows:

```
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                    new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                Iterator iter = multiparts.iterator();
                System.out.println(multiparts.size()); // this is giving me zero
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                    String fileName = item.getName();
                    File file = new File(filePath + File.separator + fileName);
                    item.write(file);
                }
                //File uploaded successfully
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
            }
        } else {
            // error occured
        }
```

One more thing I want to mention is that before the request hits this servlet a login filter is used to redirect unauthorized users.

The Form is like this:

```
  <form action="ChangeAvtar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="change_avtar">
      <a onclick="document.getElementById('file').click()" >Edit</a>
      <input type="file" id="file" style="display:none" onchange="javascript:uploadAvtar();"/>
  </form>


function uploadAvtar() {
    document.getElementById("change_avtar").submit();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your input element doesn't have a `name` attribute, which I believe is required. Does it make a difference if you add one?

Comment: @Petter: Thanks a lot that was the problem and your suggestion solved it. Several silly mistakes I make.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working :)